# How to debug failed `kops update cluster`

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I had a working kops cluster. I deleted some unneeded `ig`s and updated the cluster. Now kubectl won't connect to the cluster. I get the following error: `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp {ip} i/o timeout`.

How do I go about debugging the issue?

Answer (score 3):

as a first step I would try to run it again with higher log level, there logs are really good. 
Note you probably want to redirect to a file ...

```
kops <whatever> -v 10 &> log.txt
```